# Python Watchdog issue - missing events

Tags: python, watchdog

I am using Python Watchdog to monitor a folder on Ubuntu. It's working fine with 1 or 2 files, but when I moved 50 files by command `mv *.xml dest_folder` then it received only 2 events and processed only 2 files. Below is the code.

```
def on_moved(self, event):
    try:
        logger.debug("on_moved event :" + str(event) )
        self._validate_xml(event.dest_path)
    except Exception as ex:
        logger.exception(ex)
```

If I comment out `_validate_xml` function then I receive all 45 events.

Can any one tell me what is exactly happened in the Watchdog and what is the best solution for this?

Comment: Sorry, even commenting _validate_xml function its receiving 2 events only.

Answer (score 5):

I haven't used Python Watchdog, but from a generic real-time systems perspective,

- processing xml with `_validate_xml` can be slow, and make you miss events.
- event = similar to an interrupt, handling should be as fast as possible.

To more you do while handling an event, the less "real-time" your system becomes. What you can do is offload the xml validity check to another process and exchange messages with a `Queue` (message would be `event.dest_path`) the paths you have seen moving. Your event handling will be as simple as putting messages on a queue, and the files can be processed in batch by the consumer of the queue.

In short:

- instantiate a `Queue`
- `fork()` process
- in the `on_moved` handler, put messages on the queue,
- in the forked process, pop messages from the queue and call `_validate_xml`.
- you may optionally leverage [`multiprocessing.Pool`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) do validate xml files in parallel.

good luck.

**EDIT:** tested out on my system; most of the comments above seem not to apply because watchdog's code seems to handle `threading` just fine.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer, api
from watchdog.events import LoggingEventHandler, FileSystemEventHandler, FileMovedEvent
import logging


def counter_gen():
    count = 0
    while True:
        count += 1
        yield count

class XmlValidatorHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    sleep_time = 0.1
    COUNTER = counter_gen()
    def on_moved(self, event):
        if isinstance(event, FileMovedEvent):
            print '%s - event %d; validate: %s' % (
            type(self).__name__, self.COUNTER.next(), event.dest_path)
            time.sleep(self.sleep_time)

class SlowXmlValidatorHandler(XmlValidatorHandler):
    sleep_time = 2
    COUNTER = counter_gen()

def get_observer(handler):
    observer = Observer(timeout=0.5)
    observer.event_queue.maxsize=10
    observer.schedule(handler, path='.', recursive=True)
    return observer

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    event_handler = LoggingEventHandler()
    observer1 = get_observer(XmlValidatorHandler())
    observer2 = get_observer(SlowXmlValidatorHandler())
    observer1.start()
    observer2.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer1.stop()
        observer2.stop()
    observer1.join()
    observer2.join()
```

Wasn't able to reproduce your issue. some pointers:

- check queue `maxsize`, if you already have items in there and they don't get handled in a timely fashion, then my guess is that the `timeout` kicks in and the `event` is lost. You may want to resize in that case.
- check `timeout`, if it is configured, you may want to tune that parameter.

Maybe a more complete snippet would help us help you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick response. In code provided by you just i changed one line `observer.schedule(handler, path='./mont', recursive=True)`

Comment: and put 45 files by mv command in mont folder and i get only 2 events for both Handler. Below is the print msg  <br>*XmlValidatorHandler - event 1; validate: /home/devtool/test/mont/invalid_test_invalid_data_type.xlsx
 SlowXmlValidatorHandler - event 1; validate: /home/devtool/test/mont/invalid_test_invalid_data_type.xlsx
XmlValidatorHandler - event 2; validate: /home/devtool/test/mont/valid_test_offers_terms_HDVOD_SDEST.xlsx
SlowXmlValidatorHandler - event 2; validate: /home/devtool/test/mont/valid_test_preview_missing.xlsx* </br>

Comment: Even change the size of queue to 100 then also same.